# Dos aplicaciones Angular sobre la misma API NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, api, express

me gustaria poner dos aplicaciones en producción de Angular distintas, pero ambas corren sobre la misma API. Tengo el panel de administracion y la aplicacion del usuario separadas en dos proyectos, y se que lo logico hubiera sido poner todo en el mismo proyecto, pero ya no tengo tiempo para cambiarlo

Estoy configurando el app.js, he configurado la ruta de la aplicacion de usuario (client), y la del admin por otro lado, pero cuando accedo a la ruta, la de admin no me funciona. La de client va sobre el 4200, y la de admin sobre el puerto 4300, asi que no deberia de haber conflicto con eso. Soy nuevo en esto y estoy siguiendo un curso, pero la verdad es que no me responden a mi duda

```
app.use('/', express.static('client', {redirect:false}));
app.use('/admin', express.static('admin', {redirect:false}));
```

Gracias!

Comment: Cual es el error que te da?

Comment: Simplemente no me carga, se me queda la pantalla en blanco. Solo carga la primera ruta, la de client, pero si pongo la de admin, no me carga esa aplicacion

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El código de tu pregunta debes copiarlo y pegarlo en modo texto, no como imagen. Por otro lado, tu pregunta no es suficientemente clara. ¿Qué significa 2 aplicaciones en producción y que usan puerto 4200 y 4300? ¿Acaso tienes en *producción* el servidor webpack de Angular?. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, ahora lo arreglo y disculpas, soy nuevo por aqui. Dos aplicaciones que quiero poner en produccion, no que esten en produccion, no fui lo suficientemente claro. Me refiero a que tengo dos proyectos de Angular, que trabajan a la vez sobre la misma API. Como tengo configuradas las rutas en la imagen, no me funciona, y se 'supone' que al entrar a localhost:puerto/admin, me deberia de cargar la aplicacion admin, y si voy a /, la de cliente. Esto no me esta funcionando correctamente, y solo me funciona esta ultima. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tus tags, pones `nodejs` y `express`. Imagino que el cursillo que sigues ya te ha hecho instalar el módulo `cors`, porque Angular & NodeJS, node bloquea las peticiones de Angular por no ser del mismo origen.

Doy, entonces, por supuesto, que tienes el módulo `cors` instalado (`npm i cors`).

Por defecto, cors se confgiura para dejar pasar solo a 1 origen. Por eso solo te funciona uno de los proyectos Angular.

Tienes que optar por un **CORS dinámico**, que se puede hacer con la librería cors. Según su documentación (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin) tienes que hacer esto en tu fichero donde inicies todo (me decanto por donde pones los `app.use()`).

Tendrás algo así:

```js
// Opciones
var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
}
// Usar CORS en la app
app.use( cors( corsOptions ) );
```

**Y tienes que poner algo así**:

```
// Dominios permitidos
var whitelist = ['http://localhost:4200','http://localhost:4300']
// Opciones
var corsOptions = {
    // Origin pasa a ser una función
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        // Si el origen está en la lista, dejo continuar
        // "|| !origin" es para permitir peticiones REST Server-2-Server (se puede omitir)
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
          callback(null, true)
        } else {
          callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
     }
}
// Usar CORS en la app
app.use( cors( corsOptions ) );
```

Comment: Me devuelve el siguiente error en el navegador--->    Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: Quizás esto te lo solucione: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632496/failed-to-load-module-script